# Can you convert a method to a string in Java in the same way you can convert a function to a string in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, function, return

In javascript, if you want to return a function in its entireity, you would execute something like the following:

```js
function sum(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}

console.log(sum.toString());
// expected output: "function sum(a, b) {
//                     return a + b;
//                   }"

console.log(Math.abs.toString());
// expected output: "function abs() { [native code] }"
```

Is this possible in the Java language?

Comment: I don't know JavaScript well, but I think the answer is no.  Java just doesn't support copying code around like this.  It's a much more traditional model, where all methods are pre-compiled before execution.

Comment: Yeah, it's not possible with Java or other compiled language because the code converted to bytecode or machine code

Answer (score 0):

In Java, code is compiled into bytecode, and the JVM interprets that, so you can't print the code inside a method.

If you want to pass a method reference, you can do it with Java 8. 
If you want to print the name of the method you are in, you could use something like [`getEnclosingMethod()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getEnclosingMethod--) or get the current stack trace, depending on what you need.